# Item.Move in outlook not "Moving"

Tags: vba, outlook, copy

I have the below VBA that works fine.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Set MySents = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub


Private Sub MySents_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim targetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set objNS = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Select Case Item.SenderName
    Case "Sender1"
        Set targetFolder = objNS.Folders("Folder1").Folders("Sent Items")
    Case "Sender2"
      Set targetFolder = objNS.Folders("Folder2").Folders("Sent Items")
End Select

Item.Move targetFolder

End Sub
```

If I, however, change just the last line to

```
Item.Copy targetFolder
```

I get a "Error 450: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."
Can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MailItem.Copy does not take any arguments. It is a function that returns the copy of the given message. You can then move it to any folder

```
set NewItem = Item.Copy 
NewItem.Move targetFolder
```

Comment: Ah, that did it. Thanks